# Natural functions that converge to 1

Tags: functions, collatz-conjecture

What are some examples of functions that given a positive integer x converge to 1 using only natural operations (add, sub, div, mul).

An example would be the collatz conjecture, although it requires the use of modular arithmetic so it's not the best example.

Comment: The collatz sequence is not known to converge to 1 for all initial conditions.

Comment: Collatz can be represented without modular btw. But yeah it's still an open problem

Comment: Note: Collatz sequences (even if the Collatz conjecture is true) do not converge to $1$, they go into the cycle $1, 4, 2$

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive example is the function $f(x)=1$.

---

Of course your assertion that the Collatz map on $\mathbb{Z}$ will converge all positive integers to $1$ has never been proven, so it does not serve as a good example.